# What are "d-smooth sequences?"

Tags: algorithm, relationship, sequences

I have a homework problem that tells me this:

[image]

I can't seem to make sense of what d-smooth means. Can someone please help explain it in a more understandable way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence is d-smooth if you can increment/decrement each number at most d times to obtain a (strictly) increasing sequence.

Comment: So what would d be for sequence.. say t = {8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}? Would it be -1?

Comment: @Habit `d` has to be a positive integer (due to the absolute sign in the second part of the definition). In your example, indeed `d=7`.